# Print/Write multiple Select Statements into a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, printing

When I click my `Print` button, I need to run 10+ complex queries on my database and write/print the results.

I need them to print in a single text file/pdf, whichever is easier.

It wouldn't be feasible to use a Gridview as I have many queries. There is no manipulation going on, just a sequence of select statements.

Do you have a tutorial I can refer to? Or a concept I can use?

Comment: make your complex queries into a stored procedure and use your gridview

Comment: What about the headers? Different queries return different tables. Can you refer me to a tutorial?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Stored Procedure with those 10+ complex queries. Fetch that/those resultset in a `DataSet` as collection of multiple `DataTable` s, and then you can manipulate those `DataTable` s individually with their 'Headers'.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a tutorial as I am a first timer?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://amin-sayed.blogspot.in/2008/10/in-this-article-ill-demonstrate-how-to.html) for `DataTable to PDF print` option.

Comment: And for `adding multiple resultset in dataset`, read (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313935/how-do-i-store-multiple-results-from-a-stored-procedure-into-a-dataset)