# How to fetch data for a news feed like system?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have few tables as shown below

```
Polls

PollId  Question Option

1        What      1
2        Why       4

Updates

UpdateId  Text 

1        Sleep
2        Play
```

Polls and updates are just two sample tables (In reality there are more tables like ,photos, videos,links etc). But when a user visit his home (like facebook new feed) he must be displayed with data relevant to him  (no such data included in this example). ie I want to select data from all tables with less number of query executions. (ie, I want to present a mixture of datas, ie polls, photos, videos etc )

Currently, I'm fetching only ids and type (ie which table) from all of the tables and gather further data while iterating through this resultset. (ie from c# calling another SqlQuery) .

Is there a way to query the data from whole tables at once? (OUTER JOIN?, UNION?)

Or simply,

How can I select different type of entities at once in a single sql Query?

Comment: I'd probably encode it as an XML, and parse it on client. But make sure to test the performance on both sides (and in the middle).

Answer (score -1):

You could write your query so that you have one long select list for everything you want and it all comes back in one result set but I suspect that wouldn't work too well because you might have varying numbers of different types of items per user.

If you really must have it all in one hit then you can issue multiple queries in one go and get multiple result sets back. To handle this you can use an ADO.Net DataSet. See [this SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313935/how-do-i-store-multiple-results-from-a-stored-procedure-into-a-dataset) (but not the accepted answer - see Vikram Dibyal's answer as that gives a very basic overview of what I think you're asking for).

I won't copy and paste the stuff from the linked thread, just head over and take a look.