# SQL Server 2005 : how to 'access' XML table parameter in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I created a web service method that calls a stored procedure, which accepts an XML input parameter, in SQL Server 2005.

I've created one in SQL Server 2008 and got it working but not in SQL Server 2005. The GridView shows the correct number of rows and columns but all are blank.

**EDIT:** I removed the try-catch when filling the result set to the dataset ds_result and received this error instead:

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

C# for generating XML:

```
    DataSet CollectedReceivingData = new DataSet("CollectedReceivingData");

    DataTable SR_Header = CollectedReceivingData.Tables.Add("SR_Header");
    DataTable SR_Details = CollectedReceivingData.Tables.Add("SR_Details");

    SR_Header.Columns.Add("receiving_id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    SR_Header.Columns.Add("job_no", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    SR_Header.Columns.Add("item_id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    SR_Header.Columns.Add("expiry_date", typeof(DateTime));
    SR_Header.Columns.Add("remarks", typeof(string));
    SR_Header.Columns.Add("rcv_qty", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

    SR_Header.Rows.Add("327051", "0381021", "21848", "02/03/2016", "This is a remarks test.", "50");
    SR_Header.Rows.Add("327052", "0381021", "21849", "02/05/2016", "This is a remarks test for item 2", "25");

    SR_Details.Columns.Add("receiving_id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    SR_Details.Columns.Add("pallet_id", typeof(string));
    SR_Details.Columns.Add("qty_in_pallet", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    SR_Details.Columns.Add("expiry_date", typeof(DateTime));
    SR_Details.Columns.Add("remarks", typeof(string));
    SR_Details.Columns.Add("warehouse_id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    SR_Details.Columns.Add("location_id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

    SR_Details.Rows.Add("327051", "327051-001", "24", "02/03/2016", "This is a remarks test.", "2", "36");
    SR_Details.Rows.Add("327051", "327051-002", "5", "02/03/2016", "This is a remarks test.", "2", "36");
    SR_Details.Rows.Add("327051", "327051-003", "5", "02/03/2016", "This is a remarks test.", "2", "36");
    SR_Details.Rows.Add("327051", "327051-004", "15", "02/03/2016", "This is a remarks test.", "2", "36");

    SR_Details.Rows.Add("327052", "327052-001", "5", "02/03/2016", "This is a remarks test.", "3", "2");
    SR_Details.Rows.Add("327052", "327052-002", "15", "02/03/2016", "This is a remarks test.", "3", "2");
    SR_Details.Rows.Add("327052", "327052-003", "5", "02/03/2016", "This is a remarks test.", "3", "2");

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    WebService1 wsobject = new WebService1();
    ds = wsobject.UpdateCollectedReceivingData(CollectedReceivingData);
    gvReceiving.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    gvReceiving.DataBind();
    gvReceiving2.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
    gvReceiving2.DataBind();
```

Web method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet UpdateCollectedReceivingData(DataSet ds)
    {
        DataSet ds_result = new DataSet();
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringWS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
        objConn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[SP_Receive]"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = objConn;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@x", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = ds.GetXml();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            //try
            //{
                da.Fill(ds_result);
            //}
            //catch
            //{
            //}
        }

        objConn.Close();

        return ds_result;
    }
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Receive]
    (@x XML)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @t1 TABLE ([receiving_id] [int] NULL,
                       [job_no] [int] NULL,
                       [item_id] [int] NULL,
                       [expiry_date] [datetime] NULL,
                       [remarks] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
                       [rcv_qty] [int] NULL
                      )

    DECLARE @t2 TABLE ([receiving_id] [int] NULL,
                       [pallet_id] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
                       [qty_in_pallet] [int] NULL,
                       [expiry_date] [datetime] NULL,
                       [remarks] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
                       [warehouse_id] [int] NULL,
                       [location_id] [int] NULL
                      )

    INSERT INTO @t1 ([receiving_id], [job_no], [item_id], [expiry_date],
                     [remarks], [rcv_qty])
        SELECT 
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@receiving_id','int') as [receiving_id],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@job_no','int') as [job_no],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@item_id','int') as [item_id],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@expiry_date','datetime') as [expiry_date],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@remarks','nvarchar(255)') as [remarks],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@rcv_qty','int') as [rcv_qty]
        FROM 
            @x.nodes('//CollectedReceivingData/SR_Header') as xmlVals(rowvals)

    INSERT INTO @t2 ([receiving_id], [pallet_id], [qty_in_pallet],
                     [expiry_date], [remarks], [warehouse_id],
                     [location_id])
        SELECT 
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@receiving_id','int') as [receiving_id],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@pallet_id','nvarchar(20)') as [job_no],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@qty_in_pallet','int') as [item_id],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@expiry_date','datetime') as [expiry_date],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@remarks','nvarchar(255)') as [remarks],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@warehouse_id','int') as [warehouse_id],
            xmlVals.rowvals.value('@location_id','int') as [location_id]
        FROM 
            @x.nodes('//CollectedReceivingData/SR_Details') as xmlVals(rowvals)

    SELECT * 
    INTO #tmp1 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            t1.receiving_id as receiving_id,
            error_message = CASE
                    WHEN t2.receiving_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Item has already been received.'
                    WHEN total_rcv_qty > t1.rcv_qty THEN 'Total received quantity exceeded the quantity to be received.'
                    ELSE NULL
                END
         FROM   
             (SELECT    
                 SD.receiving_id, SH.job_no, SH.item_id, 
                 SH.rcv_qty, SUM(qty_in_pallet) as total_rcv_qty
              FROM @t2 SD
              INNER JOIN @t1 SH ON SH.receiving_id = SD.receiving_id
              GROUP BY SD.receiving_id, SH.job_no, SH.item_id, SH.rcv_qty, SD.receiving_id) t1
         LEFT JOIN 
             StockIN_Header t2 ON t1.receiving_id = t2.receiving_id
         LEFT JOIN 
             StorBest.dbo.item_master IM ON t1.item_id = IM.itemid) AS tmp1

    SELECT * 
    INTO #tmp2 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             SD.receiving_id, SD.pallet_id,
                error_message = CASE
                    WHEN WLV.warehouseid IS NULL THEN 'Invalid location_id.'
                    WHEN W.warehouseid IS NULL THEN 'Invalid warehouse_id.'
                    WHEN SD2.pallet_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Pallet has already been received'
                    ELSE NULL
                END
        FROM    @t2 SD
                    LEFT JOIN StorBest.dbo.Warehouse_Loc_VIEW WLV ON SD.location_id = WLV.LocationID
                    LEFT JOIN StorBest.dbo.Warehouse W ON SD.warehouse_id = W.warehouseid
                    LEFT JOIN StockIN_Details SD2 ON SD.pallet_id = SD2.pallet_id
        ) AS tmp2

        SELECT * FROM @t1
        SELECT * FROM @t2

    --  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT error_message FROM #tmp1 UNION ALL SELECT error_message FROM #tmp2) AS t WHERE error_message IS NOT NULL) = 0
    --    BEGIN
    --      INSERT INTO StockIN_Header SELECT * FROM @t1 
    --      INSERT INTO StockIN_Details SELECT * FROM @t2
    --    END

        END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for the note @marc_s, will definitely avoid puting the sp_ prefix again.

Comment: Found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932071/custom-datetime-formats-when-using-dataset-writexml-in-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow wont let me use a comment because of rep, but what happens when you execute just the stored procedure? Do you get anything?

Comment: I executed the SP and it worked just fine. Does this have something to do with the parameter passing from my c# code?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the following line and hit F10. Then hover over ds, and look at the tables. Is you dataset getting populated? ds = wsobject.UpdateCollectedReceivingData(CollectedReceivingData);

Comment: No, it doesn't populate.

Comment: Okay, so we know the problem isn't the stored procedure, and your c# looks good. So the problem is in your web method. Your dataset is not getting filled. My bet is your stored procedure is returning two result sets but not filling the second dataset. 'code' da1.Fill(DS, "Table1");
da2.Fill(DS, "Table2");

Comment: Sorry but I'm pretty new to C# and I'm quite confused with the 'code'. Do I create 2 instances of SqlDataAdapter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313935/how-do-i-store-multiple-results-from-a-stored-procedure-into-a-dataset